# forEach instead of for loop

Tags: foreach, functional-programming

I am dealing with this function to see whether a certain number is in an array of numbers. If it is it should return true otherwise false. 
I have this piece of code, that is perfectly working below. However, could you simplify it even more(e.g. avoid using a for loop and instead use forEach?)

Thanks

```
   function findNumber(number){
   for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if (array[i] === number){
   return true }
   }
   return false
   }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like functional programming to me.

Comment: `array.includes(number)`

Comment: So many ways to do the same thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for improvements to working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Something that semantically is similar to your code and "looks functional" could be:

```
const findNumber = number => array.includes(number);
```

There really is no reason to use `Array.prototype.forEach`. And to be honest, in a "truly functional style" the `Array.prototype.forEach` is almost never used (since its purpose is to make side effects, and that is what you try to avoid with choosing FP).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: honourable mention: `Array.prototype.find`

Answer (score 0):

```
function findNumber(arr, number){

var result = false;

arr.forEach(function(item, index){

    if(item === number) result = true;
});

return result;
```

}

Btw. I think it would be easier and more simple to simply use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:wbamberg/Examples_on_top/Array.prototype.indexOf():v2) or [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/includes) methods.

Answer (score -1):

```
  // I guess var array is already declared
  function findNumber(number){
     let test = false
     array.forEach(function(nbr){
         if(nbr ==(=) number ){
            test = true
         }    
     })
     if(test == true) { 
         return true
     } else {  
         return false
       }
  }
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: forEach is not defined`

Comment: My bad i made a mistake , i change it

Comment: It's a great cargo cult programming example.

Comment: Re edit: This appears to be longer and more complicated than the original code. It doesn't seem to meet the design goal the question asks for.

Comment: This is a way to find your number in your array using forEach. Just use array.includes(nbr) to get better perfs